# AVCaptureDevice Low Light Boost swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avcapturedevice

Does anyone know how to set up low light boost for your ios camera app? This is the code i have but can't make it to work.

```
let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    do {
                try backCamera?.lockForConfiguration()
                if (backCamera?.isLowLightBoostSupported == true) {
                   backCamera?.automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable = true
                }
                 backCamera?.unlockForConfiguration()
                 }
                 catch{
                     print(error)
                 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don`t need that. Put this in the didMoveToView:

```
captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
```